# What kind of plant is this? It has maple-like leaves but is a fast-growing weed

Tags: identification, weeds

[image: plant]

I've scoured the internet but cannot seem to identify this plant. It is growing in the Southeastern United States and is around 3 to 4 ft high. It grows fairly quickly, so I assume it's some kind of weed, but I wanted to be sure of what it was before I pulled it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like [*Broussonetia papyrifera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_mulberry) the "paper mulberry" which although native to Asia has been introduced elsewhere and in Florida for instance is a Category II invasive:

[image: Category II invasive]

[Brisbane City Council](http://weeds.brisbane.qld.gov.au/weeds/paper-mulberry) list it as a weed, provide many aids to identification  and have an image that seems a close match despite some variation in the very unusual leaf shape across specimens and age of specimen:

[image: Broussonetia papyrifera]
(*Image courtesy of Asad Shabbir*).

It is fast growing (up to 20 m in height) so should probably be removed as soon as possible, though I would be inclined to keep a little (under control!).

Comment: This is 100% the right answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

I may be way off target but since you said it's fast-growing, I wonder if it might be a very large vine just getting started. I don't know plants in the southeastern States but when I did some checking (as I find the shape of the leaves very interesting), I came across a wild grape species native to your area - Mustang grape (*Vitis mustangensis*). Here's the University of Texas site on Vitis mustangensis with lots of photos. They do say that the degree of lobbing in the leaves can vary greatly even in the same plant. http://www.sbs.utexas.edu/bio406d/images/pics/vit/vitis_mustangensis.htm
[image]

And from the Lady Bird Johnson Wildflower Center: https://www.wildflower.org/gallery/result.php?id_image=14245[image]

Somehow, I don't think that's what your plant is but who knows.

Comment: Lobing does vary greatly within the plant, some are completely oval! But it definitely isn't a vine, and the leaves are serrated. @pnuts The paper mulberry may be the correct. Could I get an answer with more information?

Comment: I also don't think it is the right plant. Venation is different (and not a like in Vitis), also the original is toothed (and not like in Vitis).,

Comment: Should I delete the answer since it's wrong? I agree with it being paper mulberry. I shouldn't try to look up answer just before bedtime as I miss things sometimes - like the serrated top edges of the leaves. --- Or would it be better to leave the answer (but say it's incorrect) so others wouldn't mix IDing it? Either way is fine by me

Comment: @Jude I would leave it, since it may help others that are trying to identify a mustang grape with similar terms.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar plant in the Ottawa area of Canada, but it is definitely a vine, since it climbs everything, and tries its best to strangle everything it climbs! The leaves are definitely like a Maple, and since I live in the heart of Maple syrup (sugar, flakes...) country, I know them well (we have three red maples, as well as a few others). I have a picture, but it is almost the same. I assume that it is Mustang grape.